# Why portal component is not rendering in template?

Tags: angular

I use [Angular portal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal) to render components dynamically.

The component listens the new `portal$` components in subsciption:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.portal$ = this.mapLibraryService.portalBridgeService.portal$;
    this.portal$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Then  template has:

```html
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="portal$ | async"></ng-template>
```

In the console log I get component that I try to render:

[image]

But it does not rendering until I don't click everywhere or resize the window or do any actions on the page.

How to debug it and fix it?

Thats is place where I change `portal$` subject:

```
editLayer(parameters: SearchParameters): Promise<any> {
    return this.showObjects(parameters).then((response) => {  
       this.portalBridgeService.set(this.portalBridgeService.portals.EDIT);
    });
}
```

This is  `this.portalBridgeService.set(this.portalBridgeService.portals.EDIT);` how I emit data to `portal$.`

If to move:

`this.portalBridgeService.set(this.portalBridgeService.portals.EDIT);` upper from promise it works fine.

**IMPORTANT THING:**

If to make this in subscribe:

```
    this.portal$ = this.mapLibraryService.portalBridgeService.portal$;
    this.portal$.subscribe((e) => {

         setTimeout(() => cdr.detectChanges())

});
```

It starts working, it renders the component, by then no more if changes comes.

I tried another way, in root component I have:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

       public action: any;
       ngOnInit() {
          this.mapLibrary.portalBridgeService.portal$.subscribe((e) => {
            if (e.type === 'Map') {
                this.action = EditMapWrapperComponentComponent;
            }
        });
       }
}
```

Template is:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="action"></ng-container>
```

Service:

```
export class PortalBridgeService {
    private portalSubject = new ReplaySubject<Portal>();
    public portal$ = this.portalSubject.asObservable();

    public set(portal: Portal) { 
                   this.portalSubject.next(portal);
    }

}
```

I have the same problem, I get messsage but Angular does not render it in component AppComponent until I resize page or click whenever.

This is my [simplified example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkkwpc)

Comment: what change detection strategy do you use?

Comment: Default change detection. Not push

Comment: This is my simplified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkkwpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     this.portalBridgeService.set(this.reonMap.portalBridgeService.portals.EDIT);
```

Without posting the whole code it is difficult to answer with 100% confidence but based on what you have gave here I suspect that you keep a field on service which when changed you want to affect your component.

You must know that default detection strategy observes fields of current component and render any changes detected on those fields. So if you change a class field on a service it will not be detected from your current component.

If that is the case consider keeping a field on your component which you want to be rendered when changed.

Edit:
Modified your example you posted to do what you required to do

> I simplify my code and posted here, instead portal CDK I push string
> variable. stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkkwpc As result I need to
> see rendered  component

**full-map.component.ts**

```
export class FullMapComponent implements OnInit {
  portal$: Observable<string>;
  shouldShow: boolean;

  constructor(private mapLibrary: MapLibrary) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.portal$ = this.mapLibrary.reonMap.portal.portal$;
    this.portal$.subscribe((portal: string) => {
      console.log(portal);
      if (portal === 'simple') {
        this.shouldShow = true;
      } else {
        this.shouldShow = false;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    this.mapLibrary.reonMap.portal.set('simple');
  }
}
```

and **full-map.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="(portal$ | async) == 'full'">
  <app-render></app-render>
</div>

<div *ngIf="shouldShow">
  <app-render></app-render>
</div>

<div (click)="render()">Render component 2</div>
```

Now when you click app-renderer component will appear.

You must subscribe to that even during ngOnInit in order to be sure that you catch the response on time. What you did was to subscribe when the click was done, which was way late.

Comment: Yes, in component I just listen changes from service where `portal$` is changed. But I can not store this field in component because portal is created dinamically. How can I set it in component and change? I dont bealve that Angulat does not detect changes in services that injected in components.

Comment: I have added some details

Comment: I simplify my code and posted here, instead portal CDK I push string variable.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkkwpc

As result I need to see rendered `<app-render></app-render>` component

Comment: @MeganClerc check my updated answer and your previous comment will work

Comment: It works when you click it, but when you set subject portal$ outside for example id code after some seconds (setTimout) it does not work. Could we move to chat?

Comment: I have noticed if async method returns data fast it renders, if with delay does not.

Comment: `loadData()` which calls the timeout is never invoked. It should be invoked somehow, either with click or in ngOnInit

Comment: loadData I call from index.html temaplte as input propery, when it is web component as result I can  do this. And it worls. I can call API. Could I share screen?

Comment: When load data takes a lot time Angular stucks rendering until any user activity